# Fragments and FragmentPagerStateAdapter - recreation of views with same id fails

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerStateAdapter`. Every page has a list, manually managed => I create views for this rows by inflating a layout from xml. Resulting in, that views in different rows have the same id. Because the rows are inflated from XML...

The behaviour now is following:

Page 1 looks like following:

```
// Page 1:
// Row 1: EditText = "Test1" 
// Row 2: EditText = "Test2"
```

I swipe to Page 2 and then to Page 3, afterwards I swipe back to Page 1 and Page 1 looks like following:

```
// Page 1:
// Row 1: EditText = "Test2" 
// Row 2: EditText = "Test2"
```

Problem: All EditTexts display the value of the lastEditText in the list... (Note, the EditTexts have the same ID).

If I manually set the ids of my EditTexts to the row index, everything works fine.

Is this normal? Is there an easy (good) solution for that problem?

Comment: Plz post the code for your list adapter on your fragment page 1.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that my update was not saved... I don't use an adapter... I do everything manually... after the activite is attached, I update my view. I remove all existing rows from my list and add new ones...

Answer (score 1):

Tt seems like a bug in Android 3.X

The solution is setting ID's manually so they never match between fragments or resetting id's when Fragment becomes invisible.
I like the second one since it can be easily disabled or enabled and requires no special id handling.

```
/**
 * Used for resetting and restoring View id's. This is used as a workaround for
 * Android 3.x when ViewPager Fragment instances with the same layout have
 * problems referencing next focus id's.
 */
public final class ViewIdResetter {

    private final Map<View, Integer> viewMap;

    public ViewIdResetter(final View rootView) {
        this.viewMap = new HashMap<View, Integer>();
        this.fillmap(rootView);
    }

    private void fillmap(final View view) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                this.fillmap(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
        this.viewMap.put(view, view.getId());
    }

    public void clearIds() {
        for (final View key : this.viewMap.keySet()) {
            key.setId(-1);
        }
    }

    public void restoreIds() {
        for (final View key : this.viewMap.keySet()) {
            key.setId(this.viewMap.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

The Fragment

```
private ViewIdResetter resetter;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.resetter = new ViewIdResetter(view);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if (this.resetter != null) {
            this.resetter.restoreIds();
        }
    } else {
        if (this.resetter != null) {
            this.resetter.clearIds();
        }
    }
}
```

setUserVisibleHint is triggered by ViewPager when the Fragment becomes visible.
The ViewIdResetter makes sure only one Fragment at a time has the same id's set.

Comment: this seems like a good solution... the only problem I have is, you are referencing android 3.X... I'm trying my app on my 4.1 system and get this behaviour... So is this bug their too or does my problem have to be another one?

Comment: I didn't encounter that bug in 4.x. But my use case was broken nextFocusLeft() and etc references, but with data I had no problem. You can try this - it's easy to integrate and tell whether if fixed if no one has a better idea.